# Book with "sources" for wizardly power

Tags: story-identification

Many years ago, I read a book where magic-users worked together as duos, with one being the person who actually cast the spells and the other being his/her "source," a reservoir of power the active wizard drew upon. The spell-caster would describe him/herself as "sourced in" his/her partner.

Does anyone know the title of this book? I've never encountered a magical arrangement like this since.

Comment: Interesting, when did you read it? Also, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Looks like Aikonia.

Comment: Moira J. Moore's Heroes series has Sources and Shields. It's not an uncommon trope.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212614/book-where-a-group-of-teenagers-travel-to-a-fantasy-world (which is newer)

Answer (score 6):

This is probably **The Fionavar Tapestry** by Guy Gavriel Kay, consisting of three books:

1. The Summer Tree
2. The Wandering Fire
3. The Darkest Road

From [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fionavar_Tapestry):

> Historically the Council of the Mages, headquartered in Brennin, may include up to seven mages, but at the time of the story there are only three: Loren Silvercloak, and his source Matt Sören, a dwarf; Metran, First Mage, and his source Denbarra; Teyrnon, and his source Barak. Each source is bound to the mage he serves by magical rituals and oaths, and provides from his own lifeforce the energy needed to power the mage's magical works. This link can be drawn upon even to the source's death, although this will then render the mage permanently powerless. The Book of Nilsom (a grimoire belonging to a mad mage of the past) includes secret knowledge of an abominable method by which a mage may gain power from more than one source.